# Does anyone have a vbascript (or general hint) as to how to lock only part of a pivot table?

Tags: excel, vba, pivot, pivot-table

Does anyone have a vbascript (or general hint) as to how to lock only part of a pivot table?  I want to retain the ability filter on half of the pivot columns but remove the ability to collapse and expand the other columns in the tertiary and secondary columns.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can lock cells in a pivot table the same way you lock any cells.  Select them and from the Home tab:

Format > Cells... > Protection > Locked.

Then protect the worksheet.

In this small example, a pivot table has been created from F3 to F4.

```
Sub Macro1()
    Cells.Select
    Selection.Locked = False
    Range("F3:F4").Select
    Selection.Locked = True
    Sheets("Sheet1").Select
    ActiveSheet.Protect DrawingObjects:=True, Contents:=True, Scenarios:=True
End Sub
```